# How do I dynamically give a value to an existing barcode created in acrobat

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, acrobat, pdf-form

How do I dynamically give a value to an existing barcode created in acrobat.

I created the bar code in a pdf form by following [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-barcode-form-fields.html) guide.

When I type something into the form fields , the bar code does get updated with the values. However the catch is , the pdf is dynamically generated through ruby code, and the form is prefilled. However the barcode doesn't include the data dynamicallly filled into the pdf form. If I make any change in the pdf form data , the bar code is reloaded and now includes the entire form data , but this doesn't happen when the generated pdf is opened for the first time.

To summarize.

1) Added barcode to a pdf form and added javascript to calcuate bar code value.

2) Bar code gets updated with newly calcuated value as form data is changed.

3) Dynamically filled the pdf form created in step 1. All form fields are filled , but bar code doesn't include the data.

4) If I make a change to data in pdf created in 3 , the bar code gets redrawn with all the data filled on the server and also includes the data change I just made.

The problem is in step 3 , when the pdf form is filled with data on the server , I am expecting the bar code to include the data.

P.S , I have used [pdf-forms](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) to fill out pdf on server. I have also tried itext java api to fill out the form.
In addition,  with both pdf-forms and itext , I have tried to provide an initial value for the bar code. However if I do this , the barcode doesn't even show in the generated pdf and instead the provided values show.

P.S 2nd. I have also been able to generate a bar code image using itext. However I need this bar code to be updated as the user changes form data in the generated pdf. Obviously the image doesn't update. and hence I tried the above approch of using a script in the pdf to calcuate barcode value on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to understand first. In PDF, the value of a field and its appearance on the page are two different things. When created in Acrobat, the ***value*** of a Barcode Field is actually calculated based on your selections in the UI when you created it. Acrobat injects some JavaScript into the field so that when new data is entered by the user, the value of the field is recalculated and Acrobat can generate a new ***appearance*** for the barcode field (an image). If you only update value of the field on the server but don't set the "needs Appearances" property to true on the document, Acrobat won't know to regenerate the barcode appearance. You could, however, generate the barcode appearance and set that via iText but you'd need to know the JavaScript calculation in order to do so. Once the value and the appearance are set up and the needs appearances property is set, the form should work normally.

Since you have tried multiple libraries, I'm going to suggest one more. The Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit can actually do all of this for you without needing to know what field data the barcode represents. You just populate the non-barcode fields with data, tell the Toolkit to calculate the form and generate appearances and it just works. The barcode gets rendered exactly the same as it would have been if filled out in Acrobat.

Comment: You mean setNeedAppearances(true) on acroform as described here:http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-8

Comment: Yes. It's slightly different in every library but that's it.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't redraw the bar code on opoening the pdf. I still have to make some change to form data to force recalculation of barcode using the script we embedded in pdf. Also I did not set a value to the barcode field before setting "need appearances" . If I set a value to barcode field it shows as text.

Comment: Right. If you set the value of the barcode and don't set the appearance, the default appearance generator of (I'm guessing it's iText) creates an appearance for you. The Needs Appearances flag should have worked though, it's possible that some kind of appearance, even a blank one, is present for the barcode and Acrobat thinks it's OK. If you can upload an example file, I can tell you for sure. Also, you can always force the calculation to happen by adding a document level script that runs "this.calculateNow()".

Comment: I am able to generate the barcode by adding this.calculateNow() as a docuemnt level script , however I also want to be able to set the value on the server side because in somecases the pdf would be flattened and hence the barcode cannot be calculated on opening the pdf.

Comment: If you plan on flattening the file, you don't need to set the value of the barcode field, you just need to set it's appearance but you'll need to know what the calculation is that sets the value that would be used to generate the appearance. The Acrobat UI allows for several different settings that are used to create a string for the barcode value. The string is used to generate the appearance. If you own all of the PDF files, you can just have your application figure out what the value should be and then create the right barcode. Continued...

Comment: ... if you are not in control of the PDF files, then I strongly suggest you use a library that's already capable of calculating the barcode and generating the appearance automatically after populating the form with data programmatically; it's seriously non-trivial. The Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit does this. Full disclosure, I used to evangelize that product. I no longer do but I still recommend it for your use case, that should mean something :)

Comment: Thanks .. I will checkout the above mentioned product.

Comment: I did not completely understand the last comment. I am in control of the pdf ( its not encrypted ) and I also know the calculations to generate bar code. I think you are saying to move those calculations to the server to determine barcode value. Are you suggesting to generate the barcode as an image or ar you suggesting to use the calculations to provide a value to the existing barcode created using acrobat/indesign. I am skeptical about datalogics api would "just work" in case of flattening. I am going to contact them eitherways because the dynamic barcode using this.calculateNow() ..Continue

Comment: on page load works in acrobat but doesn't work in adobe reader and I guess I need to purchase readers extension for non-flattened dynamic pdfs. Not sure how to update the barcode appearance on server and flatten it.

Comment: Ah - Ok - If you are in control of the PDF and know the formula, then do the calculation on the server, create your barcode graphic, and set it as the field appearance. If you're flattening, there's no need to set the barcode value. If not, you'll also want to set the value. As for the Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit just working... I assure you, it does. It started it's life as the engine inside Adobe LiveCycle so it was engineered from the beginning to process forms including running JavaScript and creating barcodes. Datalogics has made it available to developers.

Comment: Can data logics java toolkit run the javascript embedded within pdf to generate barcode. I do not want to generate an image on the server because then it doesn't look similar to what I want. See this question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081317/why-doesnt-the-itext-barcode-fit-the-page . This will also save me from having two versions of the template pdf: one without barcode for which I generate barcode image and flatten , and another with a barcode template for which I provide form values and it would generate the bar appearance like you said.

Comment: Short answer - Yes. Longer answer... still Yes... but with further explanation. The DL Java Toolkit (JT) can run all validate, calculate, and format scripts in the PDF fields and since the barcode value is calculated behind the scenes in Acrobat, it value gets calculated by JT too. The appearance of the barcode is generated based on its value by the AppearanceGenerator class. Using JT, your application, quite literally, needs to know *nothing* about the logic behind the barcode in order to correctly create the appearance as though it were done in Acrobat.

Comment: Thanks. glad you mentioned about this library. I got an evaluation version of pdftoolkit and am waiting for the key. Will play with this tomorrow evening once I get the key.

Comment: I have another basic question about reader extending the pdf for barcodes. Right now , we fill our pdfs (owned by us) using our rails application , these pdfs are then processed by itext ( we change the size of a text box to auto if the text doesn't fit it , rails gem is very limited so we do this with itext ). Once I generate a reader extended version of the pdf using Datalogics RELite once , will I still be able to do the above operations on it using rails and itext. Or does RELite needs to be run every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135136/discussion-between-joelgeraci-and-rpant).