# Why doesn't the itext barcode fit the page

Tags: itext

I am trying to fit a 417 barcode generated by itext into the pdf page. I just spills out of the page. Also the barcode looks different compared to the barcode in adobe acrobat.[image]

[image]

I have tried and played around with different settings , nothing has worked so far.

The original adobe pdf has y/x ratio of 2, and x = 0.0133 inches and error correction 5. I have tried the same settings in  itext.

Should I create a box first and do something to fit the image in a box. ?

Comment: You didn't share the code you used to create the pdf with the 417 barcode so it's neigh impossible to help you out, but I can tell you that the barcode at the top looks like a valid 417 code that can be scanned, and the one at the bottom looks like noise that will never be scanned like a valid 417. In any case: add your code to the question.

Comment: The one at the bottom can be scanned too. Here is the link of the original pdf. https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/g-28.pdf

Comment: The one at the top is the one I created , both can be scanned but the top one spills out of page if there is more data , but the same amount of data fits in the bottom one, I did not share the code because I mentioned the barcode parameters I set. Will share the code later tonight.

Comment: Can you please share the code you used here? I have a very similar use case where I need to fill in a barcode in a PDF form. Thanks.